# Get difference between groups after grouping by 2 columns

Tags: postgresql, group-by, pivot

I have the following table:

| id | date_of_birth | gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/1990 | male |
| 2 | 01/01/1961 | female |
| 3 | 01/01/1992 | female |
| 4 | 01/01/2000 | male |
| 5 | 01/01/1980 | male |
| 6 | 01/01/1990 | female |

As output I want the difference between number of males and females per decade:

| decade_of_birth | female_minus_male |
| --- | --- |
| 1960 | 1 |
| 1980 | -1 |
| 1990 | 1 |
| 2000 | -1 |

For example, in the decade of the 90s, 1 male was born, and 2 females --> 2-1 = 1

So far I got this:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    date_of_birth DATE,
    gender VARCHAR(50)
);

insert into person (id, date_of_birth, gender) values (1, '01/01/1990', 'male');
insert into person (id, date_of_birth, gender) values (2, '01/01/1961', 'female');
insert into person (id, date_of_birth, gender) values (3, '01/01/1992', 'female');
insert into person (id, date_of_birth, gender) values (4, '01/01/2000', 'male');
insert into person (id, date_of_birth, gender) values (5, '01/01/1980', 'male');
insert into person (id, date_of_birth, gender) values (6, '01/01/1990', 'female'); 

SELECT *
FROM crosstab($$
    SELECT EXTRACT(DECADE
               FROM date_of_birth) * 10 AS decade_of_birth,
       gender,
       COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS nbr_persons
FROM person
GROUP BY 1,2
  $$, $$ SELECT DISTINCT gender FROM person; $$) AS ct( decade_of_birth int, "Male" int, "Female" int);
```

The only thing that remains is getting the difference between the 2 columns. I know I can it by writing in a subquery and simply extract the 2 columns, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way within the crosstab to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
  WITH grouped_gender 
    AS (
       SELECT *
         FROM crosstab($$SELECT EXTRACT(DECADE FROM date_of_birth) * 10 AS decade_of_birth,
                                gender,
                                COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS nbr_persons
                           FROM person
 
                          GROUP BY 1,2
                       $$, $$SELECT DISTINCT gender
                              FROM person
                           $$) 
    AS ct(decade_of_birth int, 
          "Male" int, 
          "Female" int))
SELECT decade_of_birth,
       "Female" - "Male" AS female_minus_male
  FROM grouped_gender;
```

- Inner query gets number of person per decade per gender
- Crosstab unstacks gender
- Wrapped in a CTE to access columns from Crosstab (couldn't find a more elegant solution)